# How to return the response value to the caller function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sharepoint, spfx

I am calling a function in another class, that contains a API request. I want to return the response from the API request back to the class where i called the function from. But the Console.log writes out "Promise {pending}".

```
    let test: Object = Utility.getManager(this.props.graphClient);
    console.log(test);
```

Here i call the function "getManager" in class "Utility" with a parameter.

```
public static async getManager(Client: MSGraphClient): Promise<Object> {
    return await Client
        .api("/me/manager")
        .version("v1.0")
        .get(async (error, response: any, rawResponse?: any): Promise<any> => {
            // handle the response
            console.log(response);
            return await response;
        });
}
```

Here i try to send back the response from the API request to be saved in "test".

Answer (score 1):

`getManager` is an async function, and when you call it you get a promise (like all async functions).

If you want to log the result you must:

```
let test: Object = await Utility.getManager(this.props.graphClient);
console.log(test);
```

Comment: That did not work. The thing is that the console.log(test) is written out before the Console.log(response) in the other class. so it does not wait for the return.

Comment: Can you clarify which of the `console.log` is printing "Promise {pending}", the `test` or the `response`? I suspect that `console.log(response)` is printing out "Promise {pending}" because you write `await response` *after* it.

Comment: console.log(test); is printing "Promise {pending}". Console.log(response); prints out the correct response from the API request.